# Angular2. How to print HTML tag in template, that came from @Input() parameter?

Tags: html, angular, templates, input, parameters

The idea:

```
<h2 *ngIf="tag == 'h2'"></h2>
<h3 *ngIf="tag == 'h3'"></h3>
<p *ngIf="tag == 'p'"></p>
```

I want to get the `tag` be dynamic, depending on the tag property value.
The `tag` is an `Input()` parameter

P.S.: I have tried to do:
`<{{tag}></{{tag}}>`, but it gives and error and is not working

```
<div (mouseenter)="setEditMode()" [innerHTML]="result | safeHtml" *ngIf="!editMode"></div>
<div (mouseleave)="setViewModeIfNotFocused()" *ngIf="editMode">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="content" #inputEl>
</div>
```

-

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector:    'ui-edit-field',
    templateUrl: 'edit-field.component.html'
})
export class UiEditFieldComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('inputEl')
    public inputEl: any;

    @Input('tag')
    public tag: string;

    @Input('classes')
    public classes: string;

    @Input('content')
    public content: string;

    public result: string;

    public editMode = false;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.result = '<' + this.tag + ' class="' + this.classes + '">' + this.content + '</' + this.tag + '>';
    }

    setEditMode() {
        this.editMode = true;
    }

    setViewModeIfNotFocused() {
        if (true) {
            this.editMode = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<div [outerHTML]="tag"></div>
```

but `tag` needs to contain the `<...>`, because they can't be added in the template.

If `tag` is supposed to become an Angular component, then you need a different approach. Above approach only allows to add HTML without any Angular functionality.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089093/217408

**update**

```
_content:string;
@Input('content')
public set content(val:string) : void { this._content = val; updateContent();}

ngOnInit() {
    this._updateContent();
}

_updateContent() {
  this.result = '<' + this.tag + ' class="' + this.classes + '">' + this._content + '</' + this.tag + '>';
}
```

Comment: It is not an angular component, but the approach does not fit my needs, because it breacs 'content' binding (added full source code in the question)

Comment: What do you mean with "'content' binding"?

Comment: The 'content' property. I edit it in the input [(ngModel)]="content", but when I enter back in the ViewMode - the content stays unchenged from the initialization moment. I think, I have to reassing the result variable, on the model change event.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this if you write all the content as a string in your file.ts

```
<div [innerHtml]="YourHtmlString"></div>
```

and

```
this.YourHtmlString = `<${yourInput}>whatEver</${yourInput}>`
```

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation

Comment: The approach does not fit my needs, because it breacs 'content' binding (added full source code in the question)

Comment: So you'r saying that: [innerHTML]="result | safeHtml" doesn't work?

Comment: it was breaking the 'content' property binding, but I'have fixed it, by updating the 'result' proprty reassing on model change.  (input)="calcResult()"
calcResult - is the same method ngOnInit. Now All works, thanks.

Comment: Good, so try to explain the answer in your post or add a new answer.